# How many zeros does $3z^5+21z^4+5z^3+6z+7$ have in $D$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How many zeros does $f(z)=3z^5+21z^4+5z^3+6z+7$ have in closed unit disc $\overline{D}$?

I tried using Rouche's theorem which states that for $\gamma$, a closed curve in a region $\Omega$, if $f$ and $g$ are analytic in $\Omega$ and satisfy $|f(z)+g(z)|<|f(z)|+|g(z)|$ for all $z\in \gamma$ then $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeros enclosed in $\gamma$.
I let $f(z)=3z^5+21z^4+5z^3+6z+7$ and $g(z)=-21z^4$ then $|f(z)+g(z)|=|3z^5+5z^3+6z+7| \leq 3+5+6+7=21 \leq |-21z^4|=21$ on $\gamma$ function $|z|=1$. However, we need strictly less than relation; ie. $|f(z)+g(z)|<|f(z)|+|g(z)|$ for $f$ and $g$ to have same number of of zeros.

So I can't figure out how to find the number of zeros for the function.

Comment: You know $|f+g|\le|g|$ and want $|f+g|<|f|+|g|$. So it would be enough to show that $f(z)\ne0$ for $|z|=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the input .. but I don't understand the implication.

Comment: If $f(z)\ne0$ then $|f(z)|>0$, so $|f(z)+g(z)|\le |g(z)|<|f(z)|+|g(z)|$.

Comment: Yes, that make sense! For |z|=1, the strict inequality is preserved. Thanks David.

Answer (score 3):

Taking David's hint, we want to show that $f(z) \neq 0$ whenever $|z| = 1$. Suppose by way of contradiction that this could be the case. Then
$$3z^5 + 21z^4 + 5z^3 + 6z + 7 = 0 \implies |-21z^4| = 21 = |3z^5 + 5z^3 + 6z + 7|$$
and here we may appeal to the triangle inequality, which says that
$$|3z^5 + 5z^3 + 6z + 7| \leq |3z^5| + |5z^3| + |6z| + 7 = 21$$
which equality if and only if all of the addends are each non-negative (real) multiples of some complex number $z$. So this would force $z = 1$ (as $6z$ must be a non-negative multiple of $7$). But you can verify $f(1) \neq 0$, so you can conclude that $f(z)$ is never $0$ whenever $|z| = 1$.

Comment: I follow your argument but I am still stuck with understanding David's argument.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative**:

Let $h(z)=21z^4+7$, and $g(z)=3z^5+5z^3+6z$.

So $|h(z)|>14$ for all $z \in \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|=1\} \setminus \{e^{i\pi/4},e^{3i\pi/4}\}$, and $|g(z)| \leq 14$ for all $z \in \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|=1\}$. If $z=e^{\pm i\pi/4}$, then $|h(z)|=14$ but $|g(z)|=|3z^4+5z^2+6|=|-3 \pm 5i+ 6|=|3 \pm 5i|=\sqrt{34} <14$. Thus $|h(z)|>|g(z)|$ for all $z \in \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|=1\}$. By Rouche’s Theorem, $h$ and $h+g=f$ have the same number of zeros in the unit disc.

**Note**: $h(z)=7(3z^4+1)$.

Though I think you should use the idea you started with combined with the advice others have provided here for your solution.

Comment: Thanks Matt. This could work but I need to go along with the above argument as I am supposed to use according to the textbook.